# How can I retrieve the value for the attribute from an XML file using lambda expressions?

Tags: linq

e.g. Let'say I want to get BranchName's value

```
<repo>
  <Changeset  value="abcdefg"/>
  <BranchName value="gamma"/>
  <BuildNumber  value="1.2.3.4"/>
</repo>
```

Kind of what I'm seeking:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(repoPath); 
var c = doc.Descendants("repo")..... Where(x=> x.Name == "changeset");
```

Comment: "using lambda expressions" is too vague - to you mean Linq-to-XML?  If so there are [several answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=linq+xml+attribute)

Comment: I would use XQuery to find/select nodes in an xml tree..

Comment: `doc.Root.Element("BranchName").Attribute("value").Value` - no lambda expression needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
...
var c = doc.Descendants("repo")
           .Elements("Changeset") // getting "Changeset" nodes
           .Select(x => x.Attribute("value")) // getting "value" attribute
           .Where(a => a != null) // skip nulls (just in case)
           .Select(a => a.Value) // getting "value" attribute value
           .ToList();
```

Comment: This is way overkill; if you're concerned about null attributes, then check for the attribute being null before getting the value, otherwise an exception will occur. Otherwise, just use: `doc.Root.Element("BranchName").Attribute("value").Value`

Comment: @MetroSmurf, i suppose there are many Changeset elements there and cannot guarantee names are not reused for diffirent purpose

Comment: It is overkill, but he gave me what I asked for :)